# Can l install python on a 32bit OS and 64 bit processor

Tags: python-3.x, 32bit-64bit

I tried to install, a month ago someone said I can't use 32bit OS.

If thats the case, what options are available for me to install?

Comment: It could depend on which OS you are using. https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/ has 32 and 64 bit variants for Windows. Most Linux distros would have a 32 and 64 bit variant as well.

Comment: can you describe clearly your machine (processor), OS (windows 32 bits ?) ?. It seems that you have a 32bits windows OS on a 64bits machine. Why ??

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, 32 bit OS works on 64 bit processor.

In this case, install 32 bits python version.

For windows on a PC use this link : https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.2/python-3.7.2.exe

Comment: This is more like a comment.

Comment: Its a windows OS

Comment: @JoshFriedlander yes and no. The answer is to install 32 bits version of Python.